# Poisson distribution probability (another)

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

A website averages $7$ visitors per minute.

> A) what is the probability of no visitors in one minute period.
>
> B) that s the probability of 0ne ore more visitors in a $30$ minute period.

Comment: you are encouraged to edit your post to include your thoughts and also what is the difficulty that you face.

Comment: These appear to be very standard problems using the poisson distribution.  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: As you are new to the site:  people here tend to not respond well (or at all) to questions like these that appear to be routine homework exercise and which show no effort at all.  What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Poisson distribution?Probability of expected number occuring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283635/poisson-distributionprobability-of-expected-number-occuring)